# I have a normal body but fat belly. How to get rid of it?

Tags: weight-loss, bellyfat

I have normal arms; not too much fat, normal face, normal legs e.t.c but my belly is fat. I have alot of fat in my belly and I want to specifically lose that to make my body look good. Please help!

I have a body like the person on the right:
[image: 'image']

Edit: I forgot to mention that i'ma computer programmer so i'm always sitting in front of the computer.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate? This question is a specific instance of someone being "skinny fat" a completely different scenario then the one "duplicating" this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visceral fat is the worst place to have it health wise. You should not only watch what you eat and drink, but how much. There are many places to get good advice in food and drink intake. 
Exercise is not just a good thing, but absolutely nessesary for continued good health, trouble is it's tough and time consuming, but that should not put you off. As a general rule remember fat is generated at the dining table, exercise is for strength and fitness and alone can't shift that blubber.

Comment: What should be the change in diet?

Comment: Foods high in fat and sugar have the highest calorific value, as a general rule, fat is twice as calorific weight for weight. Try never to drink fruit juice, sugary soda, and the like. Low fat milk, and plain old tap water are the very best. For anyone who drinks alchohol, remember these drinks are loaded with calories. Prepare food from fresh ingredients where possible, avoid adding sugar, go easy of the fat and oil, and if you have high blood pressure cut out the salt.

Answer (score 0):

Exercise is the answer, as well as a change of diet - everybody stores fat differently, in different places.

An important thought to bear in mind is that you don't get rid of fat in certain areas by targeting that region - ie, crunches will not shift that stomach fat.

In terms of burning the fat, cardio is a good route to go, or weightlifting, or a mix of the two.

Comment: I have started playing outdoor games for that. Will that be shfficient?

Comment: @UmerJaved: It'll help (or should), but it shouldn't be an excuse to not look at what you're eating on a consistent basis.

Comment: Should I go for the workout after that?

Comment: And what cardio exercises are good for that?

Comment: @UmerJaved: To avoid recovery issues (and burning yourself out), perhaps doing separate cardio, or doing some resistance training (weightlifting for example) on a different day would probably be best. Any cardio that you enjoy enough (or dislike the least) to do consistently is the one you should go with.

Answer (score -3):

- Never take rice at Night
- Avoid eating, just before you got to bed.
- Do some early morning exercise that brings out sweat, It makes you feel good for the whole day.
- avoid taking junk food at any time till you reduce your belly

Comment: Most of it are just myths, that have been scientifically debunked.